# Query string filter on an InfoPath lookup field

Tags: infopath, lookup-column, filter, query-string, web-part-connection

I am trying to use a query string filter to filter data on an InfoPath form using [this guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/infopath/how-to-pass-querystring-data-into-an-infopath-form).  The column that I'm trying to filter is a **lookup** field and it is not available in the list of Consumer Field Names when I connect the query string filter to the form. Are lookup fields not available when filtering by query string or is there another issue?

Comment: Did you get the solution? If Yes then can you please post the answer.